# Can 'hit' mean 'meet'?

Tags: word-meaning

I've seen an American wrote in his email:

> We gonna hit at high noon.

I figure he actually means *we will meet at high noon*. Am I getting it right? I haven't found this meaning in dictionaries anyway.

Comment: No, this is not a common colloquial usage. People say, "We went out last night and hit several bars." "I will go hit the shower now." "Hit it!" has more than one sense. It sounds like something was omitted in the email you received. More context might help.

Comment: Can you provide more context. Were they planning to rob a bank? Or murder someone?

Comment: @AIQ I don't remember the exact context. That person is a project manager and he was planning an activity for a project. In fact, we did gather together at high noon later. That's why I thought he should mean we would meet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In fact, we did **gather** together at high noon later.

Well, I think the appropriate meaning of "hit" here is "to go some place together to do something or to meet somewhere with others". Its usage is informal.

From Cambridge

> to arrive at a place or position
>
> - If we turn left at the next junction, we should hit the main road after five miles or so.

From MW

> 6(c) to arrive or appear at, in, or on
>
> - the best time to hit the stores

We often say

> You wanna hit the gym tomorrow?

This means *"Do you want to go to the gym tomorrow"*.

> We gonna hit [?] at high noon.

Even in an informal setting, that sentence is incomplete. There has to be something to hit. I am guessing its the place where you all gathered.

Comment: Yeah, it could be something in  the middle. I can't remember it exactly. Thank you for the great answer!